Question regarding when ideals of $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ are projective modules
Suppose $r, n$ are integers greater than 1, such that $r|n$. If we consider the Ideal $r(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ of the ring $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, then I need to determine the following equivalent statements:
a. The short exact sequence  $0\longrightarrow  \dfrac{n}{r}(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}) \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \longrightarrow r(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ splits.
b. $\gcd\left(r,\frac{n}{r} \right)=1$.
c. The $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$-module r($\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$) is projective.
Although I could find morphisms that make the sequence exact, I could find a way to show any equivalence between statement $b$ and the other statements. By a known equivalence for projective, I only could show that $c \implies a$. But that was about it. Any ideas or hints about getting the others would be much appreciated.

Sun-Ze/Chinese Remainder theorem...?

(a) implies that $r(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ is a direct summand of the ring, hence a direct summand of a free module, hence projective, so (a) implies (c) is also standard. For b, determine the conditions under which there is a subgroup (aka ideal) of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ that is a direct complement of $r(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$. The conditions are fairly straightforward from the point of view of modular arithmetic.

The equivalence of (a) and (c) always hold:

Theorem. Let $R$ be a ring, and let $I$ be an ideal of $R$. Assume there is a module-homomorphism surjection $f\colon R\to I$.  The following are equivalent:
(a) The short exact sequence
$$0 \to \ker f \longrightarrow R \stackrel{f}{\longrightarrow} I \to 0$$
splits.
(c) $I$ is a projective $R$-module.

Proof. If $I$ is projective, then any module surjection onto $I$ splits, hence the sequence splits, proving (c) implies (a). Conversely, (a) implies that $R\cong \ker f\oplus I$, so $I$ is a direct summand of the free $R$-module $R$, hence $I$ is projective, proving (c). $\Box$
Now consider in general $a(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})\cap b(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$, where $ab=n$. The elements of the intersection are precisely the congruence classes of multiples of $\mathrm{lcm}(a,b)$ that are between $0$ and $n$. The intersection is trivial if and only if $\mathrm{lcm}(a,b)=n=ab$. Since $\mathrm{lcm}(a,b) = \frac{ab}{\gcd(a,b)}$, it follows that the intersection is trivial if and only if $\gcd(a,b)=1$.
(a) is equivalent to $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} = \frac{n}{r}(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}) \oplus r(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$, which implies $\frac{n}{r}(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})\cap r(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})=\{0\}$; so by the above observation this requires $\gcd(\frac{n}{r},r)=1$. Conversely, if $\gcd(\frac{n}{r},r)=1$, then the intersection is trivial, and the order of $\frac{n}{r}(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})+ r(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ is $n$, so it is a direct sum and hence $r(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ is projective (being a direct summand of a free module).

Thank you Arturo. So if I understand correctly, the a to c direction, it is sufficient to find one short exact sequence like the one you showed in order to make it work?

@User666x You don't need to find anything. In the (a) to (c) direction you assume you have a sequence that splits.

This is killing the fly with the cannon, but it's different, so I'll include it.
Every quotient $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ with $n>1$ is a quasi-Frobenius ring. For this type of rings, it is known that the projective modules and injective modules coincide. So if an ideal is projective, it is also injective, and hence it is a direct summand of $R$.  Conversely, every direct summand of $R$ is projective (all direct summands of free modules are projective.)
Since all the ideals that are summands are exactly those generated by idempotents, you just need to enumerate the idempotent elements, and you have enumerated all projective modules.  You may also find it helpful that projective modules are torsionfree.

Amazing but a bit too advanced for where I am right now

@User666x I know, it is admittedly not an answer you need, but I figure getting the same place two ways is helpful to corroborate.
